# Generate for loop lists

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there anyway to generate a list using a for loop in verilog?

ex

```
logic [NUM-1:0]  [31:0] data;
logic [3:0] addr, cmd, testvalue;
logic [(NUM/2+1)*32-1:0] list;

assign list = {addr, cmd,
              for ( i=0;i<NUM;i=i+2) begin
                data[i],
              end
              testvalue};
```

This is a bit of a nonsense example but just to get the point across about selecting and concatenating  regular fixed intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Since `list` is a `reg`, it cannot be continuously driven by `data`. But if we change it to `wire`, then we can create a continuous assignment with a `generate` block as follows:

```
module main
#(parameter NUM = 8);
    logic [NUM-1:0]  [31:0] data;
    wire [(NUM/2+1)*32-1:0] list;
    
    genvar i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM ; i = i + 2) begin: genbit
        assign list[(i+1)*32-1 -: 32] = data[i];
    end
endmodule
```

If I understood correctly your intention, you want to "flatten" the `data` into a list of bits while taking every second `data` word, so the code above is using the bit selection syntax to assign chunks of 32 bits at a time. You might want to reverse the selection depending on "endianess" you want the data to be flatten with.

Comment: `'logic` can be driven continuously using `assign` as well ... no problems ...

Comment: Thanks!  I was toying around with that approach.  I guess what I'm after is something that allows multiple items in "list" including slices of data without having to create temporary wires.  Ex  list = {addr, cmd, data[5:4], data[1:0], testvalue};   It would be nice to use a "for loop" to add in slices but it seems you can only loop over complete code ( terminated by ; )  versus sub portions of code.

Comment: @Mitu my compiler is shouting at me when I do it..

Comment: That's weird. `logic` was meant to be a replacement to both `wire` and `reg` in Verilog-2009/SV,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot do it in verilog the way you proposed. You need to have the loop setting those bits separately. The only slight problem in your case is to figure out correct offsetts and widths.

BTW, your decalaration of *data* `logic [NUM-1:0]  [31:0] data;` does not correspond the proposed usage int the *for* loop. You need to swap the ranges.
Also, size of the *list* is smaller than you need for the concat. If i am not mistaken, you should use *(NUM-1)/2* to be precise. Check me :-).

I propose you use the following in order to simplify the code: use a separate temp variable for extracting elements form *data* and use it in the following concat. BTW, there is no need to use *assign*.

```
  logic [31:0] [NUM-1:0]  data; // << swap array ranges
  logic [3:0] addr, cmd, testvalue;
  logic [((NUM-1)/2)*32+$bits(addr)+$bits(cmd)+$bits(testvalue)-1:0] list; //<< fix the width

  logic [31:0][(NUM-1)/2-1:0] list_data;
  always_comb begin   
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i+=2)
      list_data[i/2] = data[i];
  end
  always_comb 
    list = {addr, cmd, list_data, testvalue};
```

or if you wish, yhou can use *assign* for *logic*

```
assign list = {addr, cmd, list_data, testvalue};
```

Another variation is to use functions. This one should be definied inside the module in order to see *data*. Or you can pass *data* as an argument.

```
  function logic [31:0][(NUM-1)/2-1:0] list_data();      
      for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i+=2)
        list_data[i/2] = data[i];
  endfunction
  
  assign // or always_comb
    list = {addr, cmd, list_data(), testvalue};
```